# how to load a whole html on ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:"/" ,
        data:{"foo": foo}, //foo is a var
        success:ƒ(data) {
            here I want to load the whole html which I am sending from my views.
        }

});
```

Comment: if you mean including html tags, then i think you should not apply AJAX at all.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you want to put it, put this as the success:

```
success: function(data) {
     $('#landingDiv').html(data);   
}
```

You can apply some classes or remove a loader as well.